# Masonry.js alignment doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im using masonry.js in order to create something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaRj6.jpg

i have applied the following jquery plugin and the script :
http://masonry.desandro.com/

```
 jQuery('.board_content').jscroll({
loadingHtml: '<div class="loading_div"><center><img src="layouts/wb10/ajax-loader4.gif" alt="Loading" /></center></div>',
padding: 0,
contentSelector: '.board_list',
autoTriggerUntil: 30,
nextSelector:'.next_button',
callback: function() {

    jQuery('.list_container').masonry({
  // options
itemSelector: '.list_container',
columnWidth: 50,

});
```

so, as i scroll through, the contents are loaded to be fitting with the masonry layout, but the problem is that they are loaded alright, but not aligned properly.

the image being overlapped and etc.

i don't think the items (.list_container) find empty space and fill them with themselves either.

am i missing anything to make it look like the image i posted above?

can anyone help me out?

here is the live site: http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request